# Why is this question voted as primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion

[Why are successful human rock climbers so dissimilar to Hominidae primates who spend extended time periods climbing?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56224/why-are-successful-human-rock-climbers-so-dissimilar-to-hominidae-primates-who-s)

The question has been closed as "opinion-based" which feels overly hostile, and is apparently based on a disagreement in the comments rather than any true reasoning on the question proper.

> generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Is it really to be believed that the evolved climbing traits of the *Hominadae* are "opinion based"?

Comment: I voted to re-open since there has actually been extensive scientific research on primate physiology and the question can likely be answered based on evidence rather than opinion. If your assumption is wrong that human climbers and primates are dissimilar, evidence to the contrary can be given as an answer. Please note that the currently accepted answer seems to be an opinion.

Comment: This Wikipedia entry may be interesting to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboreal_locomotion

Comment: Thanks for the wiki entry - that's an excellent page and really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak for others, but I voted to close because the question is pob in my opinion. Take the title for a starters:

> Why are **successful** human rock climbers **so dissimilar** to Hominidae primates who spend **extended time periods** climbing?

- What is a *successful* human rock climber? In my humble opinion, someone climbing a boulder without falling off ten times is a hero. The mainstream primate would topple out from its tree laughing about that.
- What is *dissimilar*? A few kilograms of muscle tissue more or less? I find the difference between a squirrel monkey and an orangutan (both tree dwellers) a lot bigger than the difference between a human and an orangutan.
- What is an extended time period? When I boulder, I find 5 minutes on the wall a long time. A gibbon spends most of its life in the trees.

These are just a few terms taken from the title alone that will fuel debate rather than generate explicit answers. And that's the definition of a [pob question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) -

> [P]rimarily opinion-based [questions are put on hold, because] discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well.
>   Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

Although the question may be valid as indicated by others, as of now I view it as a question that holds promise, but needs work and is rightfully put on hold.